# Is it possible to convert audio to text using a Web Speech API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, speech-recognition, recordrtc

I am working on a task to record a WebRTC video conversation and then translate it to text.

For recording the audio I am using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) and for speech recognition I want to use a Web Speech API.

Is it possible to pass a recorded audio track to a Web Speech API and then get text from it? If it is possible - are there are any articles about it?

I was only able to find the articles about Google Speech API but this API is not free...

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible :)

Comment: @Karolis, okay, probably I didn't express the question correctly :) If it possible and you know an example of it or an article, could you please share it? Thank you!

Comment: Since your question is tagged with `typescript`, this is written entirely in TypeScript and should work for you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript